# PHP static variable, need help counting in a function

Tags: php

I have a function that takes an input variable and outputs a template with the following call:

```
outputhtml($blue_widget);
outputhtml($red_widget);
outputhtml($green_widget);
```

And a simplified version of the function:

```
function outputhtml($type)
{

    static $current;
    if (isset($current))
    {
        $current++;
    }
    else
    {
        $current = 0;
    }

//some logic here to determine template to output

return $widget_template;

}
```

Now here is my problem. If I call the function in a script three times or more, I want the output to be one way, but if I only call the function twice, then I have some html changes that need to be reflected in the templates that are returned.

So how can I modify this function to determine if there are only two calls for it. I can't go back after the fact and ask "hey function did you only run twice???"

Having trouble getting my head around how I tell a function that it is not going to be used after the second time and the necessary html modifications can be used. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 5):

```
function outputhtml($type)
{
    static $current = 0;
    $current++;

    //some logic here to determine template to output
    if ($current === 2) {
       // called twice
    }

    if ($current > 2) {
       // called more than twice
    }
    return $widget_template;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `if ($current === 2) {
       // called twice
    } elseif ($current > 2) {`? It's more efficient.

Comment: Here is my problem though. If the count is one or two, I need to output a certain css class. I guess I still don't understand how to do this properly. I understand that if current === 2, but how do we know the function will not be called again? Because if it goes beyond two times, then the css class being output is different. The $current variable is referenced in the template to provide a few different things for markup.

Answer (score 1):

That would not be practical using a `static $current` inside the function; I would suggest using an object to maintain the state instead, like so:

```
class Something
{
    private $current = 0;

    function outputhtml($type)
    {
        // ... whatever
        ++$this->current;
        return $template;
    }

    function didRunTwice()
    {
        return $this->current == 2;
    }
}
```

The `didRunTwice()` method is asking "did you run twice?".

```
$s = new Something;
$tpl = $s->outputhtml(1);
// some other code here
$tpl2 = $s->outputhtml(2);
// some other code here
if ($s->didRunTwice()) {
    // do stuff with $tpl and $tpl2
}
```

The only way you can find out if a function was only called twice is by putting the test at the end of your code; but perhaps by then the templates are no longer accessible? Can't tell much without seeing more code.